# Is there ANY evidence Onecoin might not be a scam?

Tags: fraud

I, like I believe the vast majority of people here,  am convinced that Onecoin is a scam.   **I'm struggling to comprehend how reasonably intelligent people can be willing to "invest" a very large sum of money in Onecoin despite the overwhelming evidence it is a scam - and any insites here would help**

One of the issues I have is a language barrier - they speak mainly Chinese, and are influenced by things in Chinese which I am not privy to - and when I ask them to explain to me they can't - These people are not into MLM, and are not looking to make money selling packages - but they believe Onecoin is going to explode in value in China, notwithstanding the "Google held view" that its a scam.

Comment: There is a similar MLM through an organisation "Coinspace" that was apparently going to launch a cryptocurrency "S-coin" in Nov 2017 that looked like a very similar (probable) scam to Onecoin. I know of a few individuals in New Zealand that seemed convinced it was genuine, but they didn't really have the knowledge to determine otherwise and after a few hours research I am 99% sure Coinspace/s-coin and Onecoin are scams. From memory the individuals behind the organisations are extremely secretive about their identity and location.

Comment: I've just discovered there are 2 Onecoins - the one commonly known as a scam, and another unrelated one designed by a Chinese Tech company (Xunlei), and also known as Wankebi.